# Deleted questions don't show as deleted on the home page

Tags: bug, design, deleted-questions, homepage

Repeatedly in the recent past, when I reloaded the home page and clicked on something, I was taken to a deleted post. Here is one example, from just now:

[image: Screen shot of Meta start page]

In this image, I have selected the title of a post which shows as recent, but is actually deleted:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390233/quickalerts-help

Curiously, the post immediately after it correctly shows as deleted. (Finally made 10k rep a few weeks ago, which brings me this "privilege". :-)

This is Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133 (Official Build) (x86_64)
on [macOS Ventura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura), in incognito mode. I generally reload the page by clicking the Meta logo which links back to the home page itself.

https://shouldiblamecaching.com?

Comment: Yes from the score in your screenshot, which is -1, looks like your browser saved a cache of the questions list as the score when deleted is -5. However, something doesn't add up. The deleted questions do not appear when reloading, but only when clicking the "show X questions with new activity", so it looks like your browser somehow activated that script. Something is odd, but can't know if on your side only, or also something on SE side.